# NullPointer on ImageIcon after migrating project to Maven

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans, imageicon

I have an application with a GUI created with NetBeans form editor, that was working with no problems, but when i added Maven to it, it started giving `NullPointersException` on every Image the GUI has.

---

1. This is how it looks in the editor, and how it looked before adding
   Maven

[image: Working GUI]

2. This is how the Icons were set up

[image: Icon Setup]

3. And this is the Project Structure, the Images are in the images
   packet
    The selected file is the main GUI and where everything is
   called from

[image: Project Structure]

3. And this is the error i get (The first icon, it does it for every other line that sets up any icon)
   [image: Error]
4. And this is the line generated by NetBeans that sets up the icons (768) 
   [image: Code Line]

I'm a bit confused since it all worked before and the editor still points to the correct images, but when compiled it all breaks, and i dont know enough about Maven to imagine what could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about NetBeans (I stopped using them 10 years ago), but I know, that non-java files cannot be in src/main/java, but in src/main/resources. Otherwise they won't be added into resulting JAR file.

Comment: Yes, for me it was weird to have them inside src, but it did work before, that's what bothers me and the people that made this app are no longer on the company so i cannot ask for their reasons

Comment: Well, before Maven it was possible in IDEs to do that (in my code (15 years ago - it was before I knew Maven or maybe Maven didn't exist yet - I had all files (java & non-java files) in src directory ... because there weren't separate src/main/java and src/main/resources directories).